# 'app --help' should go to stdout or stderr?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, stdout, stderr

I think stdout, so you can easily grep, what do you think?

Comment: The possibly really correct [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8813/should-the-usage-message-go-to-stderr-or-stdout) ;-)

Answer (score 15):

`stdout` if the user requested it with `--help` for example, makes it easier to pipe to less, grep it etc.

`stderr` if you are showing the help text because there was a problem, e.g. parsing the command line arguments.

Comment: Well, (s)he specifically said "app --help" so I assume that "--help" is recognized as a command line argument.

Comment: I was just suggesting a case where you might send help to stderr

Comment: Not "might" use stderr but "should" use stderr in the non-`--help` case: If you're showing the help text because there was a usage problem, you don't want that usage message to be mixed up with your output (which might be going to a file or into a pipeline or to somewhere else the operator won't get a chance to see it).

Comment: I agree. It's been 14 years, so I've improved it!

Answer (score 13):

Well, it's an *explicit* request for help so it should go to output.

If for some reason you can't output the help or the user spells "help" wrongly then, by all means, send that to *error,* since that would be diagnostic information.

Users that know what they're doing can use the infamous `"2>&1"` if they want errors on standard output.

Answer (score 12):

Only errors go to `stderr`. This is in no way an error, it does exactly what the user had in mind, which is print usage information.

Comment: Not "only errors"; **everything that is not output** goes to stderr. Logs go to stderr. Prompts go to stderr. Informational and diagnostic messages go to stderr. _But_ you are right: When a program is run with `--help`, the usage message is the intended output, so it belongs on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, so I'd say stdout....

Comment: **stderr is not only for errors** -- it's for absolutely everything intended to be read by a human operator rather than sent through whatever pipeline or file is receiving the program's intended output. (But then, when called with `--help`, a usage message _is_ the intended output; so this is right that stdout is the correct place, but faulty in the reasoning used to get there).

Answer (score 0):

**netcat** is the only application I can think of that would redirect -h to stderr, and I can't for the life of me fathom why.

I suppose if you're outputting the help information because someone used improper arguments, you might want to redirect it to stderr, but personally even then I wouldn't use stderr because I don't think spamming error logs with fullblown help text is useful - I'd rather just output a single error pointing out the arguments were malformed to stderr. If someone is explicitly calling your application using -h or --help, then you really shouldn't redirect it to stderr.

Comment: stderr isn't just for error logs -- it's for _display to the human operator_, which is why (for example) shell prompts go to stderr rather than stdout. stdout goes into pipelines, so it'll often be parsed or consumed by a separate program. (The word of POSIX is that stderr is for "diagnostic" content, whereas stdout is only for output; knowing when a program is ready for more input, as indicated by a prompt, falls into the diagnostic category).